# Fix compilation magento errors

Tags: php, magento

I want to enable magento compilation, but when I enable it I see follow errors:

> Warning: include_once(.../includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '.../includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/.../includes/src:.:/usr/share/php') in .../app/Mage.php on line 36
>
> Warning: include_once(.../includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /.../app/Mage.php on line 37
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '.../includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.../includes/src:.:/usr/share/php') in .../app/Mage.php on line 37
>  
> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in .../app/Mage.php on line 53

Can anybody help me to fix them? I want compilation to be enabled. In Internet every answer on this question was disable the compilation. I want the compilation to be enabled. Just for information my magento version is 1.7.0.0

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Answer (score 10):

did you change access rights on `/includes` directory? Because, after the compilation, compiled source codes reside in `/includes/src` directory!

```
$ chmod o+w includes includes/config.php

# if its not work, do following
$ chmod -R 777 includes/
```

**Modify :**
To close the compilation mode, open the file `includes/config.php` and comment out the following line :

```
define(’COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’); 
#define(’COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’stat’);
```

to

```
#define(’COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’);
#define(’COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’stat’);
```

If you want to enable compilation mode then go to admin section press the "RUN COMPILATION" button.

**Summary :**
I guess, you had forgetten to set directory permission before the compilation process therefore the compilation process has not been create compiled source code directory!

**Remarks :**
The compilation process might be headache. On each code modifications, you should compile again or contrary, you should disable to compile before the modification or extension installation. Some extensions are trouble with that. That is why so many people do not want to use in this option. Also, in v2.0 of Magento, the compilation process dropped, not available anymore!

Comment: Anton, check `includes/` directory. Are there any file/folder available in there? If, there arent'y any folder, seems to me you have compilation problem. Best way to get rid of them, disable compilation from `includes/config.php`, look modified code.

Comment: I have a stat folder in includes and all files and folder in includes are with 777 permision and I continue to see the errors

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir: Thanks it works for me after closing the compilation mode. i want to know one thing is there any problem to the site by closing the compilation mode???

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the compiler like Oğuz Çelikdemir recommended and then click on "Start compilation process" (or something like that. It's "Kompilierungsvorgang starten" in German). This initiates the compilation process rather then just "activating" it. This worked for me.